# Combinations of a Multi-set with generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the number of 5-combinations of the multi-set {4*a, 4*b, 4*c} using generating functions.

Because I am finding combinations I know that I have to use ordinary generating functions and not exponential generating functions.

I can first represent this as $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$$
$$=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$$

I'm not sure where to go from here though- I would greatly appreciate any advice or help! 
Thanks.

Comment: You *could* expand that polynomial (though that's probably not the cleanest way to do it)

Comment: After expanding it, what would I do to find the exact number of 5-combinations?

Comment: As already mentioned in the answer, you'd be looking for the coefficient to $x^5$. (Remember, the exponents in generating functions *mean* something; it's not just a magic formula)

Comment: If I'm looking at the coefficient of x^5 wouldn't it be -3? Can you explain your comment a little more or help me find more information on that. Thanks!!

Comment: Given that the polynomial has zero negative signs, I haven't a clue where you got a negative sign from.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong expression- my bad! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3 = (1-x^5)^3/(1-x)^3 = (1-3x^5 +3x^{10} -x^{15})\displaystyle\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} $. Can you find a taylor series expansion for the second term in the product?